# Crashes when reading a member pointer of a structure from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I have the following structure, class and function snippet:

structure:

```
struct myData
{
  short index;
  char  name[32];
}
```

class:

```
class myFoo
{
...
public:
   short    count;
   myData** data;
...
}
```

function:

```
int Do_Bar(myFoo vFoo)
{
  ...
  myData* data = *vFoo.data;
  for (short i=0; i<vFoo.count; ++i)
  {
    Printf("%3d %s", data.index, data.name);
  }
  ...
}
```

function call:

```
...
myFoo foo;
SomeAPI_GetCompleteObjectList(&foo);
Do_Bar(foo);
...
```

But my code crashes with these code. But if I removed the parameter and create a `myFoo` class in `Do_Bar()` function instead, the code works fine:

```
int Do_Bar(myFoo vFoo)
{
  myFoo foo;
  SomeAPI_GetCompleteObjectList(&foo);
  ...
  myData* data = *vFoo.data;
  for (short i=0; i<vFoo.count; ++i)
  {
    Printf("%3d %s", data.index, data.name);
  }
  ...
}
```

Why is it? And how to resolve this?

**EDIT1:**

I forgot to mention that the initializations of `foo` is done before the function call. This was initialized using an API.

I modified the code for this.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile! `data` is a pointer, and you use `.` to access members instead of `->`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given memory to pointer `data` in line `myData* data` and trying to assign something to it.Alternative method are either

define `myData data` then use `&data` as pointer

or allocate memory using dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of *undefined behaviors* in that little piece of code...

- You have a double-pointer, but never "point" either of them to anything. This mean they will point to random memory locations.
- You print an uninitialized character array, which means it contains random data.
- And since you don't do any initialization at all, `foo.count` will also contain a random value, which may be negative or very large.

And last bot not least, like I said in my comment, that code should not even compile as you use the wrong syntax for the access of the members in the structure.